# How to calculate PDF of a Binomial Experiment in R

Tags: r, probability, probability-density, bernoulli-probability

I know you can create a binomial Experiment with the Code

```
tenCoinFlips <- rbinom(10000,10,0.5)
```

But how can you calculate the PDF of this experiment. I know Dbinom will give you the exact PFD but is there a way to calculate the empirical PDF of an experiment?

Comment: You mean like was the the observed proportion of each outcome? do `table(tenCoinFlips)/length(tenCoinFlips)`

Comment: I tried that but adding all those up gives a number greater then 1 which would be impossible, I meant getting the probability density if that helps

Comment: I should have typed sum() rather than length(). My bad.